# Awk-html format scripting

Tags: html, unix, awk

i'm in middle of one requirement.i want to give color to heading using Awk. i used below code but it displays full color for this table so anyone please help to achieve this.

below is my code:

```
awk 'BEGIN{print "<table border=1 width=100% cell spacing=0 cell padding=0 align=center>"  {print "<tr>";for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {print "<td bgcolor=red>" $i"</td>";print "</tr>"} END{print "</table>"}' mail_send.txt
```

Note: the mail send.txt file contains data needs to be printed in table.

Answer (score 0):

I've added couple missing braces - also fixed typos in cellspacing cellpadding - added NR==1 check for bgcolor attribute

```
awk '
BEGIN {
  print "<table border=1 width=100% cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 align=center>"
} # this brace was missing
{
  print "<tr>"
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
# set bgcolor attribute only for first line
    print "<td" (NR>1? ">": " bgcolor=red>") $i "</td>"
    print "</tr>"
  }
} # this brace was missing
END {
  print "</table>"
}
'
```

Comment: thanks. i have edited as per your comments.awk 'BEGIN{print "<table border=1 width=100% cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 align=center>"}{print "<tr>";for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)print "<td>" $i"</td>";print "</tr>"} END{print "</table>"}' mail_send.txt  but i want to Display color only for first row. i mean where NR=1 it should be in color. can you please suggest for that.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to test the line number (`NR`) but you don't need a loop to surround each field with text, a `gsub()` will do:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    print "<table border=1 width=100% cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 align=center>"
}
{
    gsub(/[^[:space:]]+/,"<td" (NR>1? "" :" bgcolor=red") ">&</td>")
    print "<tr>" $0 "</tr>"
}
END {
    print "</table>"
}

$ cat file
stuff nonsense
foo bar

$ awk -f tst.awk file
<table border=1 width=100% cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 align=center>
<tr><td bgcolor=red>stuff</td> <td bgcolor=red>nonsense</td></tr>
<tr><td>foo</td> <td>bar</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: i tried the above code i'm getting error :awk 'BEGIN {print "<table border=1 width=100% cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 align=center>"}{gsub(/[^[:space:]]+/,"<td" (NR>1? "" :" bgcolor=red") ">&</td>") print "<tr>" $0 "</tr>"}END {print "</table>"}'  mail_send.txt

Comment: It would've been useful if you included the error message. Without that how could we help debug the error?

Comment: sorry my mistake. this the error i'm getting:syntax error and illegal statement  near line 1.

Comment: You are using old, broken awk (/bin/awk on Solaris) which must never be used. On Solaris use /usr/xpg4/bin/awk - that's the closest to POSIX compliant on Solaris.